# Multi Table wiht like statement: Works in Toad - not in FME SQL Query

Tags: sqlite, join, multi-table

So I have a multi table joiner that I have been succesful with inside of Toad but I cannot get to excute inside of a SQLite transformer in FME.

I am essentially wanting to join the `Region` table to the `Entry` table if the column `Entry.Category` contains `Region.Region_Name`.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
select Entry.Category, REGION.REGION_NAME
from Entry
   join REGION on Entry.Category like ('%' + REGION.REGION_NAME + '%')
```

Can anyone think of a reason why I might be having trouble? I know yall might not be familiar with FME.

thanks!

Comment: What's the result of what you're trying? An error? An empty query result? Too many query results?

Comment: Empty when I run it in FME, I get matches in Toad